# Count Nan-Values per Column in an ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Problem:
I have a ndarray (2000,7) and I want to count the numbers of Nan's per column and save it in an ndarray

Tried:

```
number_nan_in_arr = np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(arr))
```

But this count the total number of nan's over all columns

Solution: ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `axis=0` to count null per column:

```
number_nan_in_arr = np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(arr), axis=0)
```

Example:

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([[0, np.nan, 7, 0],
              [3, 0, 2, np.nan]])
np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(a), axis=0)
```

Output:

> ```
> array([0, 1, 0, 1], dtype=int64)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Simply `sum` the `True` values:

```
number_nan_in_arr = np.isnan(arr).sum(0)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was unsatisfactory with `sum`?

Comment: nothing it works perfectly. But both methods work fine and you have more reputation, and then i thought give it to the other one

Comment: @SebastianHeeg thanks for the feedback, it's perfectly good reason, I was just afraid something didn't work as you unaccepted ;)